# Angular 2 Keep service instances when changing routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have three components which are basically using all the same `DataService`. Not because of the same data, but because of the exactly same methods and patterns:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './data-list-1.html',
})
export class DataOne  {
    constructor(private dataService:DataService) {
    }
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: './data-list-2.html',
})
export class DataTwo  {
    constructor(private dataService:DataService) {
    }
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: './data-list-3.html',
})
export class DataThree  {
    constructor(private dataService:DataService) {
    }
}
```

I can switch between the components via routes. So one question is how can I keep the states of the different DataServices within the components? As far as I know that requires different instances of `DataService`, because each holds different data:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './data-list-1.html',
})
export class DataOne  {
    constructor() {
        this.dataService = new DataService();
    }
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: './data-list-2.html',
})
export class DataTwo  {
    constructor() {
        this.dataService = new DataService();
    }
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: './data-list-3.html',
})
export class DataThree  {
    constructor() {
        this.dataService = new DataService();
    }
}
```

Now although they have the same pattern of DataService they all have their own instance with their own data. But one problem isn't solved so far. How can I keep the instance of DataService when I change routes?

Comment: Where do you provide `DataService`? If you provide it at the component that is added and removed by the router when you change the route, then the service instance will also be destroyed and recreated. You'd need to provide it at a parent component, but then they will collide if the routed components get added to the same parent.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer All components belong to the same module. That's where I provide DataService.

Comment: If you provide it at the module, then you can't have different instances (except lazy loaded modules) and the state wouldn't be lost.

Comment: You likely need to define a provider in each component and make each route sticky, https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx

Comment: @estus That sounds like an anwser, althought it seems to be more complicated that I thought.

Comment: don't define a new service instance in the constructor. use this instead: `constructor(private dataService: DataService) { /* leave constructor empty */ }`

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide the `DataService` at the AppModule level and not on each of the components.

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule],       // module dependencies
    declarations: [],           // components and directives
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],      // root component
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    providers: [DataService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

To specify the service so that each component and it's children get there own instance of the service you would want to provide the service at the component level like so:

```js
@Component({
    selector: "some",
    templateUrl: "./some.component.html",
    providers: [DataService]
})
export class SomeComponent {}
```

Comment: yes that's clear. All components belong to the same module. That's where I provide DataService.

Comment: Are you re-providing them in your components? If not then all of the components should get the same reference to the service.

Comment: yes but I don't want the same reference. Each should have it's own instance.

Comment: Sorry I thought from your question you did want them to share a reference. Please see my updated answer to give each component a separate reference to the service.

Comment: if you don't put DataService into the component's providers array then an error occurs:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for DataService.
So Teddy, how does the component use it with out putting it into  the component's providers array??

Comment: The service must be provided at some higher level in the tree. Most likely this means it should be provided in the CoreModule so that it is registered as a singleton. If you want to provide a new reference to the service to a component then you can re-provide it in the component's metadata.